# reactjs: Get Combined data out of two forms

Tags: reactjs, tabs

I have two tabs both of which has forms. on click of submit button in second tab i want data of both the forms in an object.

Following is the fiddle for it.

On click of button in tab1 , tab2 should become active and on click of button in tab2 , filled data in both the forms should be captured.

http://jsfiddle.net/rzv6Lrjh/93/

```
var Tickets = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      tickets: []
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log('this mounted')
  },
  onClick: function() {
    this.state.tickets.push(
      <IndividualTicketInput />
    )
    this.forceUpdate();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <IndividualTicketInput />
        {this.state.tickets}
        <CreateTicket createTicket={this.onClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: With React-only you have to use higher-level-components to store the data, otherwise you can use something like Redux / Mobx / Flux etc. These are basically global state handlers. And there are too many resources on the web which are describing the different techniques in details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get around React, you should forget about pushing things directly to the state. Use `setState` instead.

Hope this blog post help you understand this.

https://medium.freecodecamp.com/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b